# Behavior at limits of object size

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Section 6.5.6 C99,

> If both the pointer
> operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
> element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined

Say `size_t` is one of [0..3]. If a `char` array were size 4, index [0..3], one past the last element would be index 4, which overflows `size_t`. Would, then, the maximum object size in bytes be 3, [0..2], maximum index `SIZE_MAX - 1`, because this condition? In other words, `SIZE_MAX` is guaranteed to not be a valid index of data?

Section 6.5.3.3,

> If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E.

Which is always `2^n-1`, an odd number.

Comment: The first passage you cite is not part of the C standard and has no bearing on a language lawyer question.

Comment: I will rephrase that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are quoting C99 instead of the more modern C11/C18? I don't think that there is any difference between these standards with regard to the question. However, it would still be helpful if you clarified whether your question applies to a specific standard or not.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I just picked C99 because it was widely available. I suspect similar things from different standards of C (and C++).

Comment: "If it were size 4" is an incorrect premise.  The max size would be 3.  One past the last element would be index 3.  "The maximum object size in bytes be 3" --> Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a bit of background information:

[§7.20.3 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.3p2) states that the data type `size_t` must be able to represent numbers up to at least `65535`, i.e. that [`SIZE_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) must have a value of at least `65535`.

[§5.2.4.1 ¶1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1p1) states that an implementation must support object sizes of at least `65535` bytes in a hosted environment (but states no such requirement for a freestanding environment).

However, the fact that these two numbers are identical does not mean that an implementation's maximum supported object size must be equal to `SIZE_MAX`. That is because the numbers mentioned above only represent minimum limits that the implementation must support.

[§6.5.6 ¶8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8) states that when performing pointer arithmetic, that the pointer shall not overflow, if the pointer operand and the pointer result both point to an element of the same array object, or one past the last element of that array object.

That section of the standard does not specify that the data type `size_t` must be able to represent all indexes of an object. However, [§6.5.3.4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) does imply this, by stating that the result of the `sizeof` operator is a value of type `size_t` that represents the size of the object in bytes. By doing this, the standard implies that the data type `size_t` must be able to represent the size of the object, which also implies that `size_t` must be able to represent the index one past the last valid index of the object, because that index is identical to the size of the object, assuming that the array's elements are of type `char`.

Now, to answer your question:

> Say `size_t` is one of [0..3]. If a `char` array were size 4, index [0..3], one past the last element would be index 4, which overflows `size_t`. Would, then, the maximum object size in bytes be 3, [0..2], maximum index `SIZE_MAX - 1`, because this condition? In other words, `SIZE_MAX` is guaranteed to not be a valid index of data?

Yes, that is correct. A compliant implementation would not be able to support objects of size `4` or larger, because it would be unable to make the `sizeof` operator work with them, as specified in §6.5.3.4 of the standard.